# External Hardware Fingerprint scanner and iPhone device integration

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

1. Is it possible to integrate external fingerprint sensor with our iOS application?
2. This sensor will use data cable to connect to iOS Device. Through that cable only i need to get the fingerprint data in my application.

Let me know your comment on this. If possible please share any sample project to implement this in iOS

Comment: I guess it is possible. You would need an MFi certified hardware solution in order to make use of the lightning port. Recommending solutions is off-topic, but you could look at [Grabba](http://grabba.com)

Comment: To integrate fingerprint, do we need to enroll MFI Program for developer.

Comment: If you want to make your own hardware that connects to the lightning port, then yes.  If you use something that is already MFi certified and has an sdk, then no.

Comment: No. iOS app developers do not need to join the MFi Program. Everything app developers need is in the External Accessory Framework, which is provided in the iOS SDK

Comment: You can use the external accessory framework to communicate with MFi certified accessories, but you cannot create your own hardware to work with the lightning port without being a member of the MFi program.

Comment: Thanks Paulw11.

Comment: We are not developing the hardware.

Comment: Can you share some sample to develop with External Accessory Framework

Comment: No, because I am not a member of the MFi program, and if I was a member then the information I had would be covered by that license and I could not share it with you. You can read the public documentation on Apple's site regarding the external accessory framework. Essentially it lets you open a stream to the external accessory using either legacy Bluetooth or the lightning port. Your app needs to register the identifier for the hardware that it supports.  You will need information from whoever is developing the hardware and they will need to be an MFi licensee.

Comment: I believe there is also a form that the hardware manufacturer needs to complete in order for Apple to approve your app having access to their accessory

Comment: To integrate Finger print in my app, we need to clarify below points.
1. External Device should be enrolled with MFI program.
2. Need to check whether hardware manufacture need to approve my app to access their accessory.
3. Atlast, we can use External Accessory Framework to develop in iOS

Comment: I believe there is also a form that the hardware manufacturer needs to complete in order for Apple to approve your app having access to their accessory – Paulw11 1 hour ago
R u sure about this

Comment: Yes. For example: http://bluebamboo.helpserve.com/Knowledgebase/Article/GetAttachment/26/7 - the manufacturer needs to register your app

Comment: I am building an enterprise application. Do we need permission from manufacturing device for that.

Comment: No, not if you are not going to publish to the app store

Comment: From where we will get the protocol, to add in our plist file

Comment: From the manufacturer of the hardware you are using

Answer (score 0):

To integrate **External Finger print** sensor in our project, we need to check below points with manufacturing companies.

1. External device should be MFI certified one; MFI - Made For iPhone,iPad,iPod...
2. Need to set Protocol in Supported External Accessory Protocols key in your
   app’s Info.plist eg: COM.XXX.P25i
3. For App Store Push, the manufacture need to register our application with the external device.
4. We you are ready with above points, You can start building finger print sensor using **[External Accessory Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory?changes=_8)**

LINK : [External Accessory Programming Topics](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.692.4536&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

[Integrating Apps With MFI Certification](https://www.cumulations.com/blogs/45/integrating-apps-with-mfi-certification)

Your comments would be appreciated.